# Curl from command line to PHP server Side to use generate Historical metrics for a word with Rest Interface of Google Ads API

Tags: php, rest, curl, google-ads-api

Edit:

This the converted curl code it prints this error it's relating to A Outh 2.0 I used both Client ID and client secret and same error `{ "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED" } }`

```
   $ch = curl_init();

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v9/customers/(8519781266):generateKeywordIdeas');
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n\n\"keywordSeed\": {\n    \"keywords\": [\n    \"cofee\"\n  ]\n  }\n}");
       
       $headers = array();
       $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
       $headers[] = 'Login-Customer-Id: (2260416591)';
       $headers[] = 'Developer-Token: (z2sb0uyekDzkMbiyNpAImg';
       $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer (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)';
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       if (curl_errno($ch)) {
           echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
       }
       print_r($result) ;
       curl_close($ch);
```

This curl command code with my google's data

```
curl -i --request POST https://googleads.googleapis.com/v9/customers/(8519781266):generateKeywordIdeas \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "login-customer-id: (2260416591)" \
--header "developer-token: (z2sb0uyekDzkMbiyNpAImg" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer (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)" \
--data '{

"keywordSeed": {
    "keywords": [
    "cofee"
  ]
  }
}'
```

This's the curl command line

```
curl -i --request POST https://googleads.googleapis.com/v9/customers/(ACCOUNT NUMBER):generateKeywordIdeas \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "login-customer-id: (MCC ID)" \
--header "developer-token: (DEVELOPER TOKEN" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer (ACCESS TOKEN)" \
--data '{

"keywordSeed": {
    "keywords": [
    "cofee"
  ]
  }
}'
```

and it prints this error

```
C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>curl -i --request POST https://googleads.googleapis.com/v9/customers/(8519781266):generateKeywordIdeas \
HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1564
Date: Sat, 01 Jan 2022 18:14:44 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) 0}}@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;-webkit-background-size:100% 100%}}#logo{display:inline-block;height:54px;width:150px}
  </style>
  <a href=//www.google.com/><span id=logo aria-label=Google></span></a>
  <p><b>411.</b> <ins>That’s an error.</ins>
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: \

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
'--header' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>--header "login-customer-id: (2260416591)" \
'--header' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>--header "developer-token: (z2sb0uyekDzkMbiyNpAImg" \
'--header' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>--header "Authorization: Bearer (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)" \
'--header' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>--data '{
'--data' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>
C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>"keywordSeed": {
'"keywordSeed":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>    "keywords": [
'"keywords":' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>    "cofee"
'"cofee"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>  ]
']' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>  }
'}' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\MostafaEzzat>}'
```

so I don't know honestly how to convert to Curl PHP and parse combine and all the parameters which is in this link
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/reference/rest/v9/KeywordPlanHistoricalMetrics

Comment: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ - try this automatic converter.  What research did you do before posting this question?

Comment: First of all thank you for this converter. 
https://groups.google.com/g/adwords-api/c/r50QvLeXKDs/m/1HELo_gFDgAJ
I have a conv in this forum and it has been a month since i'm trying to implment this feature

Comment: I also have unsolved issues on Github relating to this

Comment: I'm following this doc of REST Interface of Google Ads all I want is toget Historical Metrics for a keyword through REST in PHP Server Side

Comment: I think this automatic converter not reliable I'm trying built-in examples here 
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/rest/examples
and there are many errors

Comment: This part of the converted code is that normal? it gives an error anyways
`$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Developer-Token: _ENV["{z2sb0uyekDzkMbiyNpAImg}";
$headers[] = 'Login-Customer-Id: _ENV["{2260416591}";
$headers[] = 'Authorization: _ENV["Bearer {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}";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);`

Comment: or should I make associative array and put every prefix of the value in it

Comment: It can be done either way, for the headers

Comment: Anyway the converter may not be 100% perfect but it should give you a head start, since you said you had no idea where to begin. If you're still getting problems using the converted code, please post the full code in your question (not in the comments!) and mention a errors, unexpected output  etc. which it generates.

Comment: @ADyson when i use the converted code it gives this error  syntax error, unexpected identifier "Login" the syntax has problem I assume i'll edit the question with error and full curl command line code and the converted code.
I'll be glad to help in this issue coz It has been so long since I was searching

Comment: syntax error, unexpected identifier "Login" the syntax this error gone after writing my data in the converter itself it still has issue relating to the OAuth 2.0, I guess I haveto refer to Google Ads forum again pls if you have any solutions about OAuth problem.
I editied the question with all provided code.